# How do you replace a certain item in a 2D list that is in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, banking

This is a sample code I wrote to test the logic of updating customer details. I want to take in an input for the new customer details and then replace the old value with the new details. This is for a banking service system it's the last part that I am stuck on. If anyone has any basic solution I'm sure I can implement it in my code.

I just need help with a way to update a 2D list in the file without overwriting it.

Additional Info:
I am not allowed to use extra libraries..only `datetime` and `os`
I should code in modular programming

```py
def main(): 
    def info():
        details = []
        name = input('Enter your first name')
        name2 = input('Enter your second name')
        age = input('Enter your age')

        details.append(name)
        details.append(name2)
        details.append(age)

        return details

    def filewrite(ClientDetails):
        #read and evaluate the list in the file
        clientFile = open('Details.txt','r')
        tempList = eval(clientFile.read())
        clientFile.close()

        tempList.append(ClientDetails)
        clientFile = open('Details.txt','w')
        clientFile.write(str(tempList))
        clientFile.close()

    ClientDetails = info()
    filewrite(ClientDetails)
                
    def search():
        clientFile = open('Details.txt','r')
        readList1 = eval(clientFile.read())
        clientFile.close()

        adminName = input('Enter your name:')

        for i in range(len(readList1)):
            for j in range(len(readList1)):
                if adminName == readList1[i][0]:

                    value = True
                    mylist = readList1[i]
                    Sname = readList1[i][1]

                    print(mylist)
                    print(Sname)

                    update = input('Enter the updated value')

                    with open('Details.txt','w+') as a:
                        
                        readList[i][0] = str(update)
 
    search()
main()
```

Comment: don't open the file in read mode each iteration, place the loop inside the context manager instead, also `eval` is not suggested to be used really, better to use `ast.literal_eval` but as you can't use imports, just don't store the data in the file as a list but rather in rows and columns separated by some semicolon or comma

Comment: If I save them as rows and columns can I still access data through the input of the customer's name? and is it easier to update

Comment: and can i just replace eval with 'ast.literal_eval'

Comment: it is the same for updating but it is easier to read the raw file for humans and it is safer due to not evaluating anything, if you want easier updating you need to use `json` or some database, yes you should be able to simply replace `eval` with `ast.literal_eval` (you need to `import ast` first tho)

Comment: ohh we are not allowed to import ast and not allowed to use JSON..its has very strict guidlines

Comment: well you can still use simple reading from the file, it may be harder to adapt the current code, however, but it doesn't seem too big for that, also in general you shouldn't really nest functions inside other functions, that can cause other issues because of indentation. anyways, to deal with the current situation, you simply should be able to replace the data you need in the list, after that open the file and write the whole list there. also, if you use a dictionary instead of a list it would be easier, and you are using `eval` so the file will be similar to `json` minus the security

Comment: Thank you for responding... Yes, I am nesting loops just for this sample...this is not my actual code..i created this to figure out a logic so I can later implement it in my actual code...my issue is just, is there anyway to update an item in a 2D list that is in a file or is writing to the file as rows and columns the only solution?

Comment: no, you can use your solution, you just need to update the list with looping as you do, the only difference being that after the loop you open the file in write mode and write the entire list (also you seem to not need the inner loop with `j` value and also it is better to use `for item in iterable` instead of `for index in range(len(iterable))`)

Comment: Ohh okay...I used the j loop since its a 2d array...so it needs to search for the customers name first then work with that list only

Comment: Sorry but do you have a solution on how you would update or replace an item in a 2D list in a file

Answer (score 1):

A simple example on how to edit a list:

```py
# you got a list from evaluating the file data
lst = [['Jane Doe', 35], ['Thomas Weller', 59]]

# got name from input
name = 'Thomas Weller'

# and the new name
new_name = 'Thomas Jefferson'

# not iterate over the list
for person in lst:
    if person[0] == name:
        person[0] = new_name
        break

# write the list to a file
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(lst))
```

Or a list of dictionaries which would improve readability:

```py
# you got a list from evaluating the file data
lst = [{'name': 'Jane Doe', 'age': 35}, {'name': 'Thomas Weller', 'age': 59}]

# got name from input
name = 'Thomas Weller'

# and the new name
new_name = 'Thomas Jefferson'

# iterate over the list
for person in lst:
    if person['name'] == name:
        person['name'] = new_name
        break

# write the list to a file
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(lst))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Appreciate it so muchhhh!!